# Deploy a static site to multiple regions in S3 Use a load balancer to direct the user to the closest region

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Can a static site be deployed to multiple regions in S3 and use a load balancer to direct the user to the nearest region?

I didn't try anything

Comment: Not exactly, but Cloudfront is what you're looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. setup S3 Cross-Region replication from your primary bucket to one or more buckets in other Regions: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/replication.html

   1. You can configure [a whole bucket to replicate, or just a subset of objects](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/replication-add-config.html) to replicate. Make sure you configure it so all your site assets are replicated
   2. If you would rather be able to upload/change assets in any bucket (not just a designated primary), you can [set-up bi-directional replication](https://wellarchitectedlabs.com/reliability/200_labs/200_bidirectional_replication_for_s3/)
2. Setup CloudFront to use S3 as an origin [[whitepaper](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/whitepapers/latest/secure-content-delivery-amazon-cloudfront/s3-origin-with-cloudfront.html)], [[hands-on lab](https://wellarchitectedlabs.com/security/100_labs/100_cloudfront_with_s3_bucket_origin/)]
3. Load balancing is not natively supported by CloudFront, but your options are

   1. [Failover routing](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/high_availability_origin_failover.html), where it will use onw bucket to serve requests, but if that request fails, it will use the other bucket (origin)
   2. [Routing requests based on behaviors](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cloudfront-distribution-serve-content/)

---

Alternatively, instead of step 3, you may be able to use [Multi-Region Access Points in Amazon S3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/MultiRegionAccessPoints.html). This provides a single access point that will route you to the bucket with the lowest latency.

- It looks like you can [setup the multi-Region access point as a *custom* distribution origin in CloudFront](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/MultiRegionAccessPointRestrictions.html). So this may suit your use case